# getting the union from an array of linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

I have an array of the memory address of linked list and I want to get the union of two linked list and update the index it is located at with the new linked list

If I were to do this and I combine the two linked list, what happens to the one already in the array. If I traverse it, would I get the updated linked list? Would I have to create a new linked list and assign it at the two indices? if the indices are equivalent to the data value of a node, then I would need to traverse the linked list every time I merge the two linked list. Is there a way to do this in constant time without traversing the linked list?

example:

```
list 1:
data:1 -> data:3 -> data:5

list 2:
data:2 -> data: 4 - > data: 6

array:
[list1, list2, list1, list2, list1, list2]

after union:
union list:
data: 1->data:3->data:5->data:2->data:4->data:6

array after union:
[union list, union list, union list, union list, union list, union list]
```

Comment: Are you using `std::list` or `std::forward_list`?  If not, why?  If you are, there should be functions already available that do this work, either `std::list` member functions or a set of STL algorithm functions.

Comment: Shouldn't there be two arrays **before** ? In other words - one array for "list 1" and another for "list 2"

Comment: I'm working with a linked list I created, and I'm using one array for both linked list.

Comment: @Exalino hmm.. that seems strange to me - can you explain the use of the array, i.e. why do you have it and how do you use it. Anyway, you can join the lists in constant time if you have a tail pointer. If you need to reorder the array elements it can't be in constant time.

Comment: @Exalino Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is defined in a class and the nodes of the linked list accept an int as its data so I'm using the array to keep track of the data because the user has to be able to find the first node by giving me any of the data from other nodes so If they give me 6 or 4 I need to be able to return 2 because they're in the same list and the linked list will grow so if I have to traverse it, it'll come out as really inefficient. The union does not need to be in any particular order, I just need to combine the two and I figured appending the last node to the first node of another list was the easiest way.

Comment: So if the data value 100.000 is stored into one of the linked lists, you'll have an array of (at least) 100.000 elements so that you can do direct look-up to find which list holds that data value. Is that it?

Comment: yeah, wasn't sure how to do this efficiently though. Trying to do the the lookup in constant time. while still being able to merge the two list.